# Vuex and API calls

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm trying to implement Vuex in an app I'm building to learn more about Vue.js. The idea is pretty simple: retrieving user information and a list of items (everything is stored on Firebase).

I get the idea of Vuex, but the tutorials I can find only rely on data stored locally in the `store`. I can't get my head around how it would work when the data in the `store` has to be kept in sync with an external database.

Did I totally miss something? or maybe is Vuex not the best solution for that?

Comment: See [the docs on actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html).

Comment: Do you want data in the store to be automatically updated when something changes in the database?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec That would be the ideal situation, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "the data in the (Vue.js) store to be kept in sync with an external (Firestore) database", you could do as follows, taking advantage of the [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference?authuser=0#onsnapshot) method which "attaches a listener for `QuerySnapshot` events".

Let's imagine you have a `cities` collection in your Firestore database, and each document of this collection has a field `name`, which holds the city name.

First, declare the Firebase config in a `firebaseConfig.js` file:

**firebaseConfig.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

// firebase init goes here
const config = {
  apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  authDomain: 'xxxxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  projectId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
const db = firebase.firestore();

export { db };
```

Then set-up your Vuex store as follows:

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cities: []
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_CITIES(state, val) {
      state.cities = val;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    //You may add here an action that would commit the SET_CITIES mutation
  }
});
```

Then, modify the `main.js` file as follows:

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
const fb = require('./firebaseConfig.js');

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  beforeCreate() {
    fb.db.collection('cities').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      var c = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        c.push({
          id: doc.id,
          name: doc.data().name
        });
      });
      store.commit('SET_CITIES', c);
    });
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

You are all set! Just try getting the cities array in a Component, as follows:

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="c in cities" v-bind:key="c.id">{{ c.name }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["cities"])
  }
};
</script>
```

and try adding, removing or modifying records in the database.